# Not able to render data in the webpage

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, rendering

I will get newjson_data which will have below data from backend.

1. alert will have TimeStamp —> Epochformat,Type —> meeting,sso,api,account. Need to calculate count of each and every Type meeeting,sso,api,account and add it to the alert data --> Sent it to Metric Chart
2. summary will have Acc, Sev, Summary, TimeStamp —> Using this data, I need create Table --> Sent it to Table Chart
3. acc will have ACC_ID, TimeStamp, Type —> using this data, I need create TimeSeries, Also calculate count based on the TimeStamp and add it to the acc data

I am able to see data in the console under const filterAPICall but not able render it

```
mport "@elastic/eui/dist/eui_theme_light.css";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";
import {
  EuiProvider,
  EuiSpacer,
  EuiTabbedContent,
  EuiTitle,
  EuiText,
} from "@elastic/eui";

import { Header } from "./components/Header";
import { Datetime } from "./components/Datetime";
import { MetricChart } from "./components/MetricChart";
import { TimeChart } from "./components/TimeChart";
import { TableChart } from "./components/TableChart";
import axios from "axios";

const cache = createCache({
  key: "codesandbox",
  container: document.querySelector('meta[name="emotion-styles"]'),
});
cache.compat = true;

//const data = require("./alert_collection1.json");
//const newjson_data = require("./new_json_backend.json");
//console.log("New data is :", newjson_data.data);
//console.log("Old data is :", data);
let newjson_data;
//API call
const filterAPICall = (startTime, endTime, keyword) => {
  console.log("Datetime variables are", startTime, endTime);
  //let baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/getdata?startTime=${startTime}&endTime=${endTime}&keyword=${keyword}';
  let baseURL = `https://XXX.XXX:8000/api/data?start=${startTime}&end=${endTime}&keyword=${keyword}`;
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, PUT",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
  };
  axios
    .get(baseURL, {
      headers,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // setPost(response.data);
      newjson_data = response.data;
      console.log("API call data is:", newjson_data);
      let meetingseries = {};
      let accountseries = {};
      let ssoseries = {};
      let apiseries = {};
      let tempsummary = [];
      let tempstatistics = {};
      if (newjson_data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < newjson_data.data.length; i = i + 1) {
          let keys = Object.keys(newjson_data.data[i]);
          //Create data set for Meeting alerts.
          if (
            keys.includes("alert") &&
            newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]["Type"] === "meeting"
          ) {
            let temp = meetingseries;
            if (
              Object.keys(newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]).includes("TimeStamp")
            ) {
              //let datetime =
              //  newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]["Date"] +
              //  "T" +
              //  newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]["Time"];
              //let epochtime = Number(new Date(data[i]["alert"]["Day"] + "T" + data[i]["alert"]["Time"]));
              let epochTime = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]["TimeStamp"];
              let datetime = new Date(epochTime * 1000).toISOString();
              if (Object.keys(temp).length === 0) {
                temp[datetime] = {};
                temp[datetime] = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"];
                temp[datetime]["count"] = 1;
                temp[datetime]["datetime"] = datetime;
              } else {
                if (Object.keys(temp).includes(datetime)) {
                  temp[datetime]["count"]++;
                } else {
                  temp[datetime] = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"];
                  temp[datetime]["count"] = 1;
                  temp[datetime]["datetime"] = datetime;
                }
              }
              meetingseries = temp;
              //console.log("meetingseries-->", meetingseries);
            }
          }
          //Create data set for Account alerts.
          if (
            keys.includes("alert") &&
            newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]["Type"] === "account"
          ) {
            let temp = accountseries;
            if (
              Object.keys(newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]).includes("TimeStamp")
            ) {
              let epochTime = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]["TimeStamp"];
              let datetime = new Date(epochTime * 1000).toISOString();
              //let epochtime = Number(new Date(data[i]["alert"]["Day"] + "T" + data[i]["alert"]["Time"]));
              if (Object.keys(temp).length === 0) {
                temp[datetime] = {};
                temp[datetime] = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"];
                temp[datetime]["count"] = 1;
                temp[datetime]["datetime"] = datetime;
              } else {
                if (Object.keys(temp).includes(datetime)) {
                  temp[datetime]["count"]++;
                } else {
                  temp[datetime] = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"];
                  temp[datetime]["count"] = 1;
                  temp[datetime]["datetime"] = datetime;
                }
              }
              accountseries = temp;
              //console.log("accountseries-->", accountseries);
            }
          }
          //Create data set for SSO alerts.
          if (
            keys.includes("alert") &&
            newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]["Type"] === "SSO"
          ) {
            let temp = ssoseries;
            if (Object.keys(newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]).includes("Date")) {
              let epochTime = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]["TimeStamp"];
              let datetime = new Date(epochTime * 1000).toISOString();
              //let epochtime = Number(new Date(data[i]["alert"]["Day"] + "T" + data[i]["alert"]["Time"]));
              if (Object.keys(temp).length === 0) {
                temp[datetime] = {};
                temp[datetime] = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"];
                temp[datetime]["count"] = 1;
                temp[datetime]["datetime"] = datetime;
              } else {
                if (Object.keys(temp).includes(datetime)) {
                  temp[datetime]["count"]++;
                } else {
                  temp[datetime] = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"];
                  temp[datetime]["count"] = 1;
                  temp[datetime]["datetime"] = datetime;
                }
              }
              ssoseries = temp;
              //console.log("ssoseries-->", ssoseries);
            }
          }
          //Create data set for API alerts.
          if (
            keys.includes("alert") &&
            newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]["Type"] === "API"
          ) {
            let temp = apiseries;
            if (Object.keys(newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]).includes("Date")) {
              let epochTime = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"]["TimeStamp"];
              let datetime = new Date(epochTime * 1000).toISOString();
              //let epochtime = Number(new Date(data[i]["alert"]["Day"] + "T" + data[i]["alert"]["Time"]));
              if (Object.keys(temp).length === 0) {
                temp[datetime] = {};
                temp[datetime] = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"];
                temp[datetime]["count"] = 1;
                temp[datetime]["datetime"] = datetime;
              } else {
                if (Object.keys(temp).includes(datetime)) {
                  temp[datetime]["count"]++;
                } else {
                  temp[datetime] = newjson_data.data[i]["alert"];
                  temp[datetime]["count"] = 1;
                  temp[datetime]["datetime"] = datetime;
                }
              }
              apiseries = temp;
              //console.log("apiseries-->", apiseries);
            }
          }
          //Creating summary data [2nd part] from json
          else if (keys.includes("summary")) {
            let temp = newjson_data.data[i]["summary"];
            let epochTime = newjson_data.data[i]["summary"]["TimeStamp"];
            let datetime = new Date(epochTime * 1000).toISOString();
            temp["datetime"] = datetime;

            //temp["id"] = newjson_data.data[i]["_id"]["$oid"];
            tempsummary = [...tempsummary, temp];
          }
          //Creating statistics data [1st part] from json
          else if (keys.includes("acc")) {
            let temp = tempstatistics;
            //console.log(temp);
            //Initialising all values to 0 initially
            if (Object.keys(temp).length === 0) {
              //console.log("temp", newjson_data.data[i]);
              temp["Meeting"] = {};
              temp["Meeting"]["count"] = 0;
              temp["account"] = {};
              temp["account"]["count"] = 0;
              temp["API"] = {};
              temp["API"]["count"] = 0;
              temp["SSO"] = {};
              temp["SSO"]["count"] = 0;
              //temp[newjson_data.data[i]["acc"]["Type"]]["count"] = 1;
            } else {
              if (
                Object.keys(temp).includes(newjson_data.data[i]["acc"]["Type"])
              ) {
                temp[newjson_data.data[i]["acc"]["Type"]]["count"]++;
              } else {
                temp[newjson_data.data[i]["acc"]["Type"]] = {};
                temp[newjson_data.data[i]["acc"]["Type"]]["count"] = 1;
              }
            }
            tempstatistics = temp; //Stores staistsics data as dictionary with the count of meeting, Account, API, SSO related alerts.
            //console.log("te--<", tempstatistics);
          }
        }
      }
      console.log("Meeting series is: ", meetingseries);
      console.log("Account series is:", accountseries);
      console.log("SSO series is:", ssoseries);
      console.log("API series is:", apiseries);

      let Barchartdata = [];
      const meetinglen = Object.keys(meetingseries).length;
      const accountlen = Object.keys(accountseries).length;
      const ssolen = Object.keys(ssoseries).length;
      const apilen = Object.keys(apiseries).length;

      //Combining all the alert data related to bar chart into one single dictionary.
      for (let i = 0; i < meetinglen; i++) {
        let tempMeetingarray = [];
        tempMeetingarray["DateTime"] =
          Object.values(meetingseries)[i]["datetime"];
        tempMeetingarray["Countbar"] = Object.values(meetingseries)[i]["count"];
        tempMeetingarray["Type"] = "Meeting";
        Barchartdata[i] = tempMeetingarray;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < accountlen; i++) {
        let tempAccountarray = [];
        tempAccountarray["DateTime"] =
          Object.values(accountseries)[i]["datetime"];
        tempAccountarray["Countbar"] = Object.values(accountseries)[i]["count"];
        tempAccountarray["Type"] = "account";
        Barchartdata[i + meetinglen] = tempAccountarray;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < ssolen; i++) {
        let tempSSOarray = [];
        tempSSOarray["DateTime"] = Object.values(ssoseries)[i]["datetime"];
        tempSSOarray["Countbar"] = Object.values(ssoseries)[i]["count"];
        tempSSOarray["Type"] = "SSO";
        Barchartdata[i + meetinglen + accountlen] = tempSSOarray;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < apilen; i++) {
        let tempAPIarray = [];
        tempAPIarray["DateTime"] = Object.values(apiseries)[i]["datetime"];
        tempAPIarray["Countbar"] = Object.values(apiseries)[i]["count"];
        tempAPIarray["Type"] = "API";
        Barchartdata[i + meetinglen + accountlen + ssolen] = tempAPIarray;
      }
      //console.log("Bar chart data is:", Barchartdata);
      //console.log("Summary data is:", tempsummary);
      //console.log("Metric data is:", tempstatistics);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

/*console.log("Whole time series is: ",temptimeseries);
console.log("Summary data is: ",tempsummary);
console.log("Statistics data is: ", tempstatistics);
console.log("Time series data is: ", Object.values(temptimeseries)[0]['count']);
console.log("Length is : ", Object.keys(temptimeseries).length);*/

//console.log(tempdata);

const Demo = () => {
  const tabs = [
    {
      id: "web--id",
      name: "WEB monitoring ",
      content: (
        <Fragment>
          <EuiProvider cache={cache}>
            <Datetime filterAPICall={filterAPICall} />
            <EuiSpacer size="xxl" />
            <MetricChart tempstatistics={tempstatistics} />
            <TimeChart Barchartdata={Barchartdata} />
            <EuiSpacer size="xxl" />
            <TableChart tempsummary={tempsummary} />
          </EuiProvider>
          ,
        </Fragment>
      ),
    },
    {
      id: "ZR--id",
      name: "ZR-CRC Monitoring",
      content: (
        <Fragment>
          <EuiSpacer />
          <EuiTitle>
            <h3>ZR-CRC Monitoring</h3>
          </EuiTitle>
          <EuiSpacer size="xxl" />
          <EuiText>Please add the required components in this tab.</EuiText>
        </Fragment>
      ),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <EuiTabbedContent
      tabs={tabs}
      initialSelectedTab={tabs[0]}
      autoFocus="selected"
      onTabClick={(tab) => {
        console.log("clicked tab", tab);
      }}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <EuiProvider cache={cache}>
    <Header />
    <Datetime filterAPICall={filterAPICall} />
    {/* only render if we have data */}
    {newjson_data && (
      <Fragment>
        <MetricChart tempstatistics={tempstatistics} />
        <TimeChart />
        <TableChart />
      </Fragment>
    )}
  </EuiProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Need to fix rendering issue

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).